# How to get culture-aware output with printf-like functions?

Tags: f#, printf

Is there a way to use F#'s `sprintf` float formating with a decimal comma? It would be nice if this worked:

```
sprintf "%,1f" 23.456
// expected: "23,456"
```

Or can I only use [String.Format Method (IFormatProvider, String, Object())](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ksz8yb7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ?

EDIT: I would like to have [a comma not a point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark) as a decimal separator. Like most non-English speaking countries use it.

Comment: I have edited the title and body for some more clarity and searchability. Feel free to roll it back if it's wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking a look at source code of `Printf` module, it uses [`invariantCulture`](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/printf.fs#L498). I don't think printf-like functions are culture aware.

If you always need a comma, you could use `sprintf` and `string.Replace` function. If your code is culture-dependent, using `ToString` or `String.Format` is your best bet.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. I edited my answer.

Comment: So modifying from the source i could make a `sprintf` function that also takes a CultureInfo argument ?

Answer (score 5):

It's quite a pain, but you can write your own version of `sprintf` that does exactly what you want:

```
open System
open System.Text.RegularExpressions
open System.Linq.Expressions

let printfRegex = Regex(@"^(?<text>[^%]*)((?<placeholder>%(%|((0|-|\+| )?([0-9]+)?(\.[0-9]+)?b|c|s|d|i|u|x|X|o|e|E|f|F|g|G|M|O|A|\+A|a|t)))(?<text>[^%]*))*$", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture ||| RegexOptions.Compiled)

type PrintfExpr =
| K of Expression
| F of ParameterExpression * Expression

let sprintf' (c:System.Globalization.CultureInfo) (f:Printf.StringFormat<'a>) : 'a =
    //'a has form 't1 -> 't2 -> ... -> string

    let cultureExpr = Expression.Constant(c) :> Expression

    let m = printfRegex.Match(f.Value)
    let prefix = m.Groups.["text"].Captures.[0].Value

    let inputTypes = 
        let rec loop t = 
            if Reflection.FSharpType.IsFunction t then
                let dom, rng = Reflection.FSharpType.GetFunctionElements t
                dom :: loop rng
            else
                if t <> typeof<string> then
                    failwithf "Unexpected return type: %A" t
                []
        ref(loop typeof<'a>)

    let pop() = 
        let (t::ts) = !inputTypes
        inputTypes := ts
        t  

    let exprs =
        K(Expression.Constant(prefix)) ::
        [for i in 0 .. m.Groups.["placeholder"].Captures.Count - 1 do
            let ph = m.Groups.["placeholder"].Captures.[i].Value
            let text = m.Groups.["text"].Captures.[i+1].Value
            // TODO: handle flags, width, precision, other placeholder types, etc.
            if ph = "%%" then yield K(Expression.Constant("%" + text))
            else
                match ph with
                | "%f" -> 
                    let t = pop() 
                    if t <> typeof<float> && t <> typeof<float32> then
                        failwithf "Unexpected type for %%f placeholder: %A" t
                    let e = Expression.Variable t
                    yield F(e, Expression.Call(e, t.GetMethod("ToString", [| typeof<System.Globalization.CultureInfo> |]), [cultureExpr]))
                | "%s" ->
                    let t = pop() 
                    if t <> typeof<string> then
                        failwithf "Unexpected type for %%s placeholder: %A" t
                    let e = Expression.Variable t
                    yield F(e, e)
                | _ -> 
                    failwithf "unhandled placeholder: %s" ph
                yield K (Expression.Constant text)]

    let innerExpr = 
        Expression.Call(typeof<string>.GetMethod("Concat", [|typeof<string[]>|]), Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof<string>, exprs |> Seq.map (fun (K e | F(_,e)) -> e)))
        :> Expression

    let funcConvert = 
        typeof<FuncConvert>.GetMethods()    
        |> Seq.find (fun mi -> mi.Name = "ToFSharpFunc" && mi.GetParameters().[0].ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = typedefof<Converter<_,_>>)

    let body =
        List.foldBack (fun pe (e:Expression) ->
                match pe with
                | K _ -> e
                | F(p,_) -> 
                    let m = funcConvert.MakeGenericMethod(p.Type, e.Type)
                    Expression.Call(m, Expression.Lambda(m.GetParameters().[0].ParameterType, e, p))
                    :> Expression) exprs innerExpr


    Expression.Lambda(body, [||]).Compile().DynamicInvoke() :?> 'a

sprintf' (Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo "fr-FR") "%s %f > %f" "It worked!" 1.5f -12.3
```

Comment: So would you recommend this over `String.Format`? :) +1 for sheer effort.